# Retarded Green's function for Fermions vs Bosons

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, greens-functions, many-body, propagator

Normally, retarded non-interacting [Green's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function) for [Fermions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermion) is:
$$
G_0^R(k,E) = \frac{1}{E-\epsilon_k+i\eta}
$$

But recently, I read a few research articles (for example, equation (46) of [[1]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.01908)), where they multiply $E$ with $\eta$, i.e.:
$$
G_0^R(k,E) = \frac{1}{E-\epsilon_k+iE\eta}
$$
they do this only for Bosons, for Fermions. Is there any specific reason for this extra $E$? Is there any proof for that?

Comment: Does this help: @ http://tonic.physics.sunysb.edu/~dteaney/F16_Phy505/lectures/green.pdf  ?

Comment: Or this: @ https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/220/1/012022/meta  ? Also @ https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/220/1/012022/pdf